# Will merging accounts add up the reputation?

Tags: support, reputation, merge-accounts

I am wondering if merging accounts add up the reputation?
For example if I have two accounts; "Joe" which has 300 reputation, and "johnny" which has 100 reputation, if I merge the two, will it give me a rep of 400?